# rack doesn't identified as a command in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rack, rack-middleware

I have a rails4 project `gem 'rails', '4.0.2'`,  and I have created a custom rack module in
`config/initializers/request_timer.rb`, from Ryan bates [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware?view=asciicast)

but when I run the command `rack middleware`, inside my project, it says

`-bash: rack: command not found`

I havent add the `rack` gem to my Gemfile and I believe it should come with rails by default.

Following is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html

Try:

```
rake middleware
```

Am not sure if that is what you're after

Comment: yeah that works, it should be `rake` instead of `rack`, thanks a lot :)